# Subarray selection

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to accomplish (just for fun) a sub-array selection python-like in javascript. Something like:

```
let a = ["a","b","c","d"]
console.log(a[[0,2]])
//prints ["a","c"]
```

A (kind of verbose) way could be using Proxy:

```js
var handler = {
  get: function(target, name) {
    console.log("type of name", typeof(name)) //it prints "string"!
    if (name in target) {
      return target[name];
    }
    if (name == 'length') {
      return Infinity;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(name)) {
      return target.filter((v, i) => ~name.indexOf(i))
    }
  },
  set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {
    target[property] = value;
    return true;
  }
};

var originalArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var p = new Proxy(originalArray, handler);

console.log(p[[1, 2, 4]]);
```

If I pass an array the `get` function it will be automatically converted in string! Why does it do that?

There is a way to build a structure where elements are selectable with this usage?
`a[[0,2]]`

Comment: Why not just use `.slice()`?

Comment: Because... a property name is a string?

Comment: @Pointy "just for fun".

Comment: `slice()` itself is not enough, I want to select non-sequential indexes too.

Comment: @user202729 but I pass an array..

Comment: Property names are strings. If you try to use something that is not a string, it will be *converted* to a string.

Comment: what is acually the question?

Comment: Why don't you use a member function or an external function instead? ... Why trying to mimic other languages' syntax?

Comment: @NinaScholz I edited the question and clarified the doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look for commas, because properties are strings and you get a joined string out of arrays as key.

```js
var handler = {
    get: function(target, name) {
        if (name.includes(',')) {
            return name.split(',').map(i => target[i]);
        }
        return target[name];
    },
    set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {
        target[property] = value;
        return true;
    }
};

var originalArray = ["a","b","c","d"];
var p = new Proxy( originalArray, handler );

console.log(p[[1,2,4]]);  // ["b", "c", undefined]
console.log(p['length']); // 4
```

Comment: yeah I thought about a split solution like this, I guess there is no better way. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused with p[[1,2,4]] as passing an array to the proxy. 
Here, p is an object in javascript and when we write objectName[xyz] it is the xyz property on the object we are referring to.
As get traps the **name** of the property and names of the property are of type string in javascript. Hence, the array you pass is being comprehended as a string here.